# In an apache ServerAlias directive, what does a question mark mean?

Tags: configuration, virtualhost, apache-2.4

[Apache's documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) says:

> The ServerAlias may include wildcards, if appropriate.

and

> The wildcard characters * and ? can be used to match names

My colleague claims that the question mark matches any character other than a period (`.`) and thus can be used in a "single-level" wildcard. I can't find any documentation supporting this usage.

In a `ServerAlias` directive, what does the question mark mean? Please cite documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The question mark (`?`) matches a single character, including a period.** The function used to compare hostnames and `ServerAlias`es is `ap_strcasecmp_match` ([server/util.c:212](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/5e1c73e0398d6e8b48bdece672bf1fd27d7cfdf8/server/util.c#L212)).

```
// server/util.c
int ap_strcasecmp_match(const char *str, const char *expected)
{
    int x, y;

    for (x = 0, y = 0; expected[y]; ++y, ++x) {
        if (!str[x] && expected[y] != '*')
            return -1;
        if (expected[y] == '*') {
            while (expected[++y] == '*');
            if (!expected[y])
                return 0;
            while (str[x]) {
                int ret;
                if ((ret = ap_strcasecmp_match(&str[x++], &expected[y])) != 1)
                    return ret;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        else if (expected[y] != '?'
                 && apr_tolower(str[x]) != apr_tolower(expected[y]))
            return 1;
    }
    return (str[x] != '\0');
}
```

Assuming it makes sense to test the function in isolation, it's easy to see that the question mark matches single characters, including periods.

```
ap_strcasecmp_match("foo.bar.com", "?.bar.com") // 1
ap_strcasecmp_match("f.bar.com", "?.bar.com") // 0
ap_strcasecmp_match("fg.bar.com", "?.bar.com") // 1
ap_strcasecmp_match("..bar.com", "?.bar.com") // 0
ap_strcasecmp_match("f.g.bar.com", "???.bar.com") // 0
```

A zero is a match, anything else is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your colleague is correct.  The `?` wildcard character is indeed used to match a single non `.` character valid for dns names.

You can poke around at several other documents that mention the `?` character, and *if* they describe its use they always say something like `In a wild-card string, ? matches any single character, and * matches any sequences of characters.`  Unfortunately, I think it simply was overlooked to mention everywhere the meanings of both syntaxes.

Comment: Thanks. You say "The ? wildcard character is indeed used to match a single non . character".  Would `?.example.com` match `foo.example.com`?

Comment: No.  ???.example.com would match foo.example.com, or ?.example.com would match f.example.com... but that's it.  The *.example.com would match foo.example.com as well as f.example.com

Comment: I think the `?` wildcard matches periods, actually.

Comment: nope.  No periods.